# How to call method inside the Linq query

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a repeater control and binding list content to it. But i need to get data from another list also and bind to this column.
As shown below i need to call getvalue method for every List Item in Linq query. When i try as shown below, the value for itemscount is always null

```
    public void DeptInfo() 
                    {
                    SPList olist = web.Lists["Administration"];
                    SPListItemCollection itemscoll = olist.GetItems();
                    string itemscount = string.Empty;
                    if (itemscoll.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var listcontents = (from item in itemscoll.OfType<SPListItem>()
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       itemscount = getvalue(web, item),
                                       DepartmentName = item["Title"] +  itemscount          // DepartmentName is the column in repeater                                    
                                   }); 
                        if (listcontents.ToList().Count != 0)
                        {
                            Repeater.DataSource = listcontents.ToList();
                            Repeater.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                    }

                      public string getvalue(SPWeb web, SPListItem item)
                      {
                                    SPListItemCollection spItemCollection = null;
                                    SPList olist = web.Lists["DepartmentList"];
                                    SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
                                    spQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Division' /><Value Type='LookupMulti'>" + Convert.ToString(item["Title"]) + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                                    spItemCollection = olist.GetItems(spQuery);
                                    return (spItemCollection.Count.ToString());
                      }
```

Can anyone suggest me if any change is required to call method for everyitem so that to append in the repeater.

Comment: Looks good, what I would do is to place breakpoint inside getvalue method and step to see whats wrong

Comment: I might be wrong here, but I am pretty sure that spItemCollection.Count will never return null, so not sure how you are getting null at itemscount